# Mercurial error 255 - how to revive my repository?

Tags: mercurial, machg

it's a quesion about mercurial.

I'm not a unix - guy, but use a mercurial together with MacHG for my development on Mac. Yesterday I had to change my mac, I just copied my project folder with repository on new mac, but now I can't do anything with it in mercurial. I can open project in xcode and everuthing is fine, but if I try to do anything in mercurial via terminal I'm getting this: `abort: data/.DS_Store.i@e959df7694ce: no node!`

If I try to do anything in MacHG I'm getting `Mercurial reported error number 255:
skipping unreadable ignore file '/Users/zakhar/.hgignore': No such file or directory
abort: data/.DS_Store.i@e959df7694ce: no node!`

What can I do? where can I get this .hgignore file? I don't have old mac any more.

Comment: It seems that the copy doesn't include files starting with a dot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advice you're getting about putting `.DS_Store` in your `.hgignore` file was the advice you needed back when you first setup that repo, however it wont help now.  You've already added the `.DS_Store` files in your repo on your old computer and adding a file overrides `.hgignore`.

Furthermore, it looks like when you copied the stuff from your old computer to the new computer the `.hg/data/.DS_Store.i` file and probably anything else with `.DS_Store` in it didn't copy over.

Drop to terminal on the new computer and do a `hg verify`.  If you get notifications about missing files (and it looks like you will) then you need to re-copy the repository over, or better yet clone it over with `hg clone`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I didn't know about `hg verify`. Indeed I had these files missing, I copied it via network and apparently something went wrong, thanks God I made a backup copy to usb drive, this copy is ok).

Comment: Yeah, it was probably your copy tool saying "He probably doesn't want this file it has .DS_Store in the name" not knowing that it was the repository's important history file.  Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

.hgignore file tells Mercurial, what files to ignore.

Just create a .hgignore file at location mentioned and add the following

```
# use glob syntax.
syntax: glob

*.o
*.so
*.log
*.DS_Store
.DS_Store
```

See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714820/mercurial-script-plugin-for-ignore-remove-binary-files/3714858#3714858

Also you may want to remove all .DS_Store files in your repo:

```
find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 hg remove
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I created ,hgignore file, but still have error `Mercurial reported error number 255:
abort: data/.DS_Store.i@e959df7694ce: no match found!` What shall I do with it?

Comment: Yes, I've done it, by the way where do I need to put this file ? I put it to my home (/Users/zakhar/), may be somewhere else?